# Installing Zimbra ZCS

Tags: zimbra, ubuntu-11.04

I was looking through some tutorials on how to install Zimbra ZCS on Ubuntu.

Mainly I kept coming across [this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing_zimbra_collaboration_suite_on_ubuntu).

I had two question related to the installation,

1. Zimbra only has an "Official Version" for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Can I load it on Ubuntu 11.04?
2. In the tutorial the writer talks about setting your internal DNS server with an MX record for zimbra. If I am only going use Zimbra for my external domain, do I need the internal DNS records?

**Edit**

I need to learn to read more. The DNS settings are explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./install.sh --platform-override is the command you're looking for to install on unsupported platforms.

Comment: Ah very nice. But is it stable? Because I could just as easily download the Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Heh, after you've got it up, you're on your own.  I can't speak to that, I've run it on 8.04 and 10.04, both very stable.

Comment: Ah I see, well I guess I need to get the LTS version, I am not taking any chances. Thanks